# Mouse Cursor and other overlays Invisible on Ubuntu 17.04 Live USB

Tags: unity, nvidia, usb, mouse

I am currently trying to install Ubuntu 17.04 on my computer. To do this, I created a live USB using the startup disk creator. When I boot into this live USB, everything works as it should except the mouse cursor is invisible. It also appears that other overlays (such as the dash menu, when opened via the windows key) are invisible as well. The computer has a i7-6700hq, GTX 1070, and 16 GiB of ram. The mouse also seems to work, for if I move it around and observe the screen I can get some idea where it is and use it for basic functions, such as logging off.

I tried using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to install nvidia-375 (`nvidia-\d+` package with greatest number) via a terminal. When I did this however, there was no immediate effect and logging off (with the intention of logging back on) brought about a black screen in place of any sort of login screen. Attempting to reboot uninstalls the package.

I also tried the following command, which had no effect:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.cursor active false
```

How can I install Ubuntu 17.04 on my computer?